# Scala match error with unapply

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, unapply

I'm trying out the code at http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112 and I'm getting a match error for something that doesn't look like it should throw one.

This is the original code:

```
object Twice {                              
  def apply(x: Int): Int = x * 2
  def unapply(z: Int): Option[Int] = if (z%2 == 0) Some(z/2) else None
}

object TwiceTest extends Application {
  val x = Twice(21)
  x match { case Twice(n) => Console.println(n) } // prints 21
}
```

I just added a few lines to test what happens when I pass an odd number:

```
object TwiceTest extends Application {
  val x = Twice(21)
  x match { case Twice(n) => Console.println(n) } // prints 21
  val y = 21
  y match { case Twice(n) => Console.println(n) } // throws scala.MatchError: 21 (of class java.lang.Integer)
}
```

The case for 21 or any odd number should also be handled by the unapply method in the object as far as I can tell. Can someone explain why this is not the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val x = Twice(21)
```

is the same as

```
val x = Twice.apply(21)
```

meaning that `x` will be equal to `42`. The `Twice.unapply(42)` returns a `Some(21)`, meaning that the `case Twice(21)` successfully matches the value `x == 42`.

This is why the first `match` statement prints out `21`.

The `Twice.unapply(21)` returns `None` (because `y == 21`, that is, if `y` is odd).
Whenever an `unapply` returns `None` for some value, we say that the extractor object with that `unapply` method does not **match** that value.

If a `match` statement does not match a value to any of its cases, it will throw a `MatchError`.

Answer (score 2):

It is being handled by your `unapply` method, but not the `match`. Since your `unapply` should return a `None`, it means that it doesn't meet `case Twice(n)`.

Change it to something like

```
21 match {
  case Twice(n) => println("this won't happen")
  case x => println("just " + x)
}
```